# I have a following mistake: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column students.year_course_id does not exist LINE 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Change my code! I have a following mistake: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column students.year_course_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "students" WHERE "students"."year_cour... ^ : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "students" WHERE "students"."year_course_id" = $1

Answer (score 5):

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column students.year_course_id does not
>   exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT() FROM "students" WHERE
>   "students"."year_cour... ^ : SELECT COUNT() FROM "students" WHERE
>   "students"."year_course_id" = $1

Error clearly states that `year_course_id` column does not exist in `students` table.
Create it to resolve the issue.

When you specify

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :year_course
end
```

you would need to add `year_course_id` field in `students` table referencing `year_courses` table.

**UPDATE**

Here is how you can add `year_course_id` column in `students` table by generating a migration:

```
rails generate migration AddYearCourseRefToStudents year_course:references
```

After this run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Whether it is possible to solve on another this problem? To replace these lines with others:@student_count = @year_courses ?...

Comment: `@year_courses.students` would not work unless you have `year_course_id` in `students` table. See my updated answer of how to add it.

Comment: I have in the table students a field course_id and I corrected it,

Comment: Did it work then? If not, what is the error that you get? Also, share the schema of `students` table from `schema.rb`. Add it in the question.

Comment: <%= f.text_field :stud_count, @student_count %> - How it is correct to write this line.

Comment: What is the error that you get now? Is your actual issue `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column students.year_course_id does not exist ` gone?

Comment: I solve this problem. I have field course_id in table Students. And I change this field from year_courses to @courses ?

Answer (score 1):

Kirti's answer is correct in that you definitely need to have an id column in the respective, referencing model, however, if you've already got that in place but still getting the error (like myself), here's how I resolved it:

I found saw that I was trying to delegate a different name to the column association in my model, which was tripping this up for some reason. Namely, I had:

```
has_many :document_doc_types, as: :doc_types
```

and Rails was barfing with a similar error to what you posted. After I removed the 'as: doc_types' portion, all was well again. So, this works as expected:

```
has_many :document_doc_types
```

Hope this helps.